# Custom Comparator implementation for both ASC and DESC order

Tags: java, algorithm, sorting, collections, comparator

I'm trying to find a way to define an unique implementation of `java.util.Comparator` usable for both ascending and descending ordering purpose.

I have defined a class `Golf.java` that represents Volkswagen's car. I also defined a Comparator that order `Golf` instances by horses power (`int` variable). I was wondering if it's possible to use the same comparator for both ascending and descending ordering.

GolfHorsePowerComparator.java

```
package test2.comparator;

import test2.dto.Golf;
import java.util.Comparator;

public class GolfHorsePowerComparator implements Comparator<Golf> {

    @Override
    public int compare(Golf a, Golf b) {
        return a.getHorsePower() > b.getHorsePower() ? 1 : a.getHorsePower() == b.getHorsePower() ? 0 : -1;
    }

}
```

Given a list of `Golf` how could I sort them ascending or descending using the same `java.util.Comparator` implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [`Collections::reverseOrder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#reverseOrder-java.util.Comparator-) to sort in desc order. Eg:

```
GolfHorsePowerComparator golfHorsePowerComparator = new GolfHorsePowerComparator();
Collections.sort(golfList, Collections.reverseOrder(golfHorsePowerComparator));
```

Comment: Thank you! So it would be best practice to code custom `Comparator` always ascending or descending inside a project and then use `Collections.reverseOrder(customComparator)` method to revert the ordering, right?

Comment: @Gozus19 Yes, that's exactly why reverseOrder is introduced in api.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, look at [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html). `Comparator` has a `reversed` method. You can simply do this:

```
list.stream().sorted(comparator).collect(Collectors.toList());
list.stream().sorted(comparator.reversed()).collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The first one sorts ascending, the second - descending.